# Install XAMPP from command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, installation, xampp

I am trying to install XAMPP programmatically on Windows machines and I need to change the folder where the installer puts the files. I can barely find any documentation on the installer, except for the built-in help.

I currently have the following command, which installs, but keeps putting the files in the default directory `C:\xampp`:

```
xampp.exe
   --unattendedmodeui minimal 
   --disable-components xampp_mercury,xampp_tomcat,xampp_webalizer 
   --mode unattended"
   --launchapps 0 
   --prefix D:\test
```

I was expecting that the line `--prefix D:\test` would change the directory, based on the explanation in the `--help`:

```
--prefix <prefix>                           Select a folder
                                            Default:
```

If this is not even the right argument, then what is? Because I cannot find anything else that might be related.

Thank you in advance

---

```
XAMPP 7.1.1-0
Usage:

 --help                                      Display the list of valid options

 --version                                   Display product information

 --unattendedmodeui <unattendedmodeui>       Unattended Mode UI
                                             Default: none
                                             Allowed: none minimal minimalWithDialogs

 --optionfile <optionfile>                   Installation option file
                                             Default: 

 --debuglevel <debuglevel>                   Debug information level of verbosity
                                             Default: 2
                                             Allowed: 0 1 2 3 4

 --mode <mode>                               Installation mode
                                             Default: qt
                                             Allowed: qt win32 unattended

 --debugtrace <debugtrace>                   Debug filename
                                             Default: 

 --enable-components <enable-components>     Comma-separated list of components
                                             Default: xampp_server,xampp_apache,xampp_mysql,xampp_filezilla,xampp_mercury,xampp_tomcat,xampp_program_languages,xampp_php,xampp_perl,xampp_tools,xampp_phpmyadmin,xampp_webalizer,xampp_sendmail
                                             Allowed: xampp_mysql xampp_filezilla xampp_mercury xampp_tomcat xampp_perl xampp_phpmyadmin xampp_webalizer xampp_sendmail

 --disable-components <disable-components>   Comma-separated list of components
                                             Default: 
                                             Allowed: xampp_mysql xampp_filezilla xampp_mercury xampp_tomcat xampp_perl xampp_phpmyadmin xampp_webalizer xampp_sendmail

 --installer-language <installer-language>   Language selection
                                             Default: en
                                             Allowed: sq ar es_AR az eu pt_BR bg ca hr cs da nl en et fi fr de el he hu id it ja kk ko lv lt no fa pl pt ro ru sr zh_CN sk sl es sv th zh_TW tr tk va vi cy

 --prefix <prefix>                           Select a folder
                                             Default: 

 --launchapps <launchapps>                   Learn more about Bitnami for XAMPP
                                             Default: 1
```

Comment: Try to do a `CD /D "D:\test"` first and then run your code again as you think it should be. Let me know if that helps resolve.

Comment: Sadly it still installed in `C:\xampp`

Comment: I do have the same issue. No solution found yet.

Comment: the .exe version does not allow the path change. Use the .zip or portable versions